# Which 'article' to use when we refer to a common person every time in the same passage?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I know a rule:

> I found **a** pen. **The** pen was broken.

When I introduce a *pen,* for the first time, it takes the indefinite article and **once,** it's introduced, I can proceed with the definite one.

Well, but while writing an essay on, say, on a student (any student), which article would go throughout the essay?

Example:

> The two main entities of any classroom teaching are ***a*** student and ***a*** teacher. While ***a/the*** student serves as an audience, ***a/the*** teacher is a performer. Whenever ***a/the*** student asks *a/the* teacher on any subject, they are bound to answer.

Though I have introduced a *student* and a *teacher,* I **don't want** to get specific. Throughout the paragraph, I want to talk about *any student,* *any teacher,* randomly and **not** specific. Even further, what about the entire essay? Wherever I mention *student/teacher* which article should I put? Mind it, I **don't** want to be specific, each time I want to talk on *random/any* student/teacher.

Maybe, **the last paragraph** would be...

> *A/the* student's performance depends on their own capabilities, learning curves, and top of all *a/the* teacher's support.

Now, that is the **last** paragraph...would *'a'* work? I don't want *the.* Would it be incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

Even if it's a non-specific, generic student/teacher you still use **the** because you're referring to the same student/teacher that you introduced earlier.

> The two main entities of any classroom teaching is a student and a teacher. While **a** student serves as an audience, **a** teacher is a performer. Whenever **a** student asks **a** teacher on any subject, they are bound to answer.

In the above paragraph you introduce a student and a teacher, but then afterwards you aren't necessarily talking about *the same* student and teacher that you just introduced.

To make it clearer, if you attached names it would look something like this:

> The two main entities of any classroom teaching are Andrew and Bertha. While Charlie serves as an audience, David is a performer. Whenever Earl asks Fred about any subject, they are bound to answer.

However, using **the** specifies that you're still talking about the same student and teacher you introduced at the start.

Comment: Your first and third paragraph in the answer is contradictory to each other. Specify it further.

Comment: The first paragraph is telling you what you *should* do. The third is an explanation of why the second paragraph is wrong. When you use **a** all the time, it doesn't tell us whether you are talking about 1 student and 1 teacher, 3 students and 3 teachers, or any combination of numbers. When you first introduce them with **a**, then refer to them again with **the** you specify that there is only 1 student and 1 teacher in your story, even though they are anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

This would also be grammatical:

> The two main entities of any classroom are student and teacher. The
>   student serves as audience, the teacher as performer. The teacher is
>   bound to answer whenever the student asks about any subject.

No article is needed when referring to  the noun as role.

Comment: Note that bare role NPs are "invariably replaceable by their counterparts with determiner *the*" (p.409 in CGEL by Huddleston & Pullum, 2002). I.e., the sentence is equivalent to this one: *The two main entities of any classroom are the student and (the) teacher.* (Also, the conclusion stated in this answer applies only to NPs indicating a role, functioning as predicative complements to verbs *be*, *become*, etc.; as oblique predicatives governed by *as*, and as complement of the preposition *of* following nouns like *role*, *part*, or *position*.)

Comment: I find your parenthetic remark unclear.

Comment: I apologize. "No article is needed when referring to the noun as role" is an overgeneralized conclusion. It's correct only when the noun in question indicates some kind of role (*president*, *treasurer*) and (1) functions as a predicative complement of the verb *be*, *become*, *appoint*, etc. (*Henry **became treasurer***); or (2) if the said noun functions as predicative oblique governed by *as* (***As treasurer**, I strongly support this proposal*); or (3) as a complement of *of* following nouns like *role*, *part*, or *position* (*The **role of treasurer** will fall to Henry*).

Comment: @user2684291: Can you give me an example where noun-as-role requires an article?  *President is a powerful position.*  Does that require an article?  It fails your tests (1), (2), and (3).

Comment: How about *Each position has different requirements. Goalie requires height and a wide wingspan, whereas striker requires speed and great ball-handling skills.*

Comment: CGEL says: "They cannot occur as subjects (\**I'm told treasurer strongly supports this proposal*) or objects (\**We dismissed treasurer*): in these positions they require a determiner."

Comment: The noun is not referring to the role there, but to the person occupying the role. I think many people do not understand what is meant by ***as* role** and ***qua* role**. *We're going to abolish treasurer* or *Treasurer will be abolished* or *We're going to combine treasurer and secretary into one position* would be fine.

Comment: *I'm told treasurer is going to be abolished.* refers to the role.  *Treasurer is quite pretty, don't you think?* refers to the person in the role. There, with the person, we do need the article. It should be *The treasurer is quite pretty.*

Comment: Hm. CGEL says that in *Mary washed her car*, The subject NP *Mary* is a referential expression. (The descriptions I gave you are for **non-referential** interpretations of bare NPs.) Obviously, we know *which* Mary we're talking about there. In *There are two Marys in the room*, *Mary* isn't referential. Or in *The name Mary is very popular*.

Comment: The relevancy of that last remark escapes me.  With noun-as-role or noun-qua-role the distinction is a semantic one. When you're referring to the person in the role an article is used; when referring to the role itself, no article is needed.

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to clarify the terminology used there. *Referential* means when you know what or who the NP refers to. However, you're right that the authors of the relevant chapter chose bad example sentences because in both of them you'd interpret the NP as a referential one which would then require an article.

Comment: My statement that *No article is needed when referring to the noun as role* is not an "overgeneralized conclusion". One just needs to understand what is meant  by "as role".

Comment: Okay, I didn't wanna jump to any conclusions because to me these sentences sounded weird, but I'm not a native speaker of English so I have no say. First, I asked in chat about this, and one person (a native speaker) told me your first sentence, *President is a powerful position* is ungrammatical. That made me reconsider everything you said. I went on to ask some of my acquaintances from the US and Australia (one of them is a night owl) about your examples. I didn't suggest to them there's anything wrong with these sentences, and yet they outright dismissed all of them as ungrammatical.

Comment: Are you referring to the sentences in my answer? Or in these comments?

Comment: No, just the examples starting with *President...* The one in your answer is alright, and it conforms to the description laid out in CGEL.

Comment: Well, I'm a native speaker (of AmE), studied English at university and then for five more years in graduate school, so I'll stick by my guns here and say that as long as you're using the noun *as role* no article is needed.

Comment: For example: https://books.google.com/books?id=AOQpDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT297&lpg=PT297&dq=%22Secretary+of+State+is+fifth%22&source=bl&ots=55RtWyVh2z&sig=qwVLNhTcKALbmHLJps-xOeYSpy4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGrsvEwZzcAhVHxbwKHeF1DjcQ6AEIPTAD#v=onepage&q=%22Secretary%20of%20State%20is%20fifth%22&f=false